# Executar o gif durante o load da webview

Tags: android, webview

Boa noite, estou querendo colocar um gif que apareça até que a página no **webview** seja carregada completamente... o gif já tenho, coloquei um compile e peguei o código do github, o meu problema é que não estou conseguindo executar o gif antes da web view. O meu plano é o seguinte, quero que o gif fica carregando até a página webview seja completada 100%.

Mas não estou conseguindo, alguém me ajuda?

codigo:

```
private WebView web;
    private ImageView gif;

    private String [] permissoesNecessarias = new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,
            Manifest.permission.INTERNET
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_mega_sena);

        PermissionAction.validaPermissoes(1, this, permissoesNecessarias);

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_resultados);
        gif = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);

        web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress){

                if(progress == 100){
                    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    web.loadUrl("http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/megasena#resultados");
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.gif_loading).asGif().into(gif);
                }else{

                }
            }
        });

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

Detalhe: depois da **webview** carregada, o gif aparece junto...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que é só colocar o seguinte código antes do else:

```
 gif.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Isso fara com que o gif despareça quando chegar nessa linha